# ¿Cuál es la etimología de "zurriburri"?

Tags: etimología, onomatopeyas, euskera

El otro día me encontré entre algunos sinónimos de *gentuza* la palabra *zurriburri*, por su sonoridad me pareció que podía provenir del euskera aunque no conocía la palabra pero sí otras similares y fuí al DLE a ver que decía:

> **[zurriburri](https://dle.rae.es/?id=cYjQwHw)**
>
> **1.** m. Barullo, confusión.
>
> **2.** m. coloq. Sujeto vil, despreciable y de muy baja esfera.
>
> **3.** m. coloq. Conjunto de personas de la ínfima plebe o de malos procederes.

No pone nada sobre la etimología y buscando por internet tampoco he encontrado gran cosa, en algunos sitios pone que es de origen incierto y en una web que no consigo recordar decía que era una onomatopeya de un ruido bronco.

Answer (score 3):

> **zurriburri**
>
> Most previous speculation on this word can be quickly dismissed. Corominas 1:4:874b lists *zurriburri* as a compound of *zumbar*, but refers to Morawski instead of explaining. Morawski («rimées» 121) dismisses Múgica’s (*ZRPh* 30, 114) hypothesis that it is student macaronic Latin (*turris burris*), only noting that it is similar to words studied by Schuchardt<sup>9</sup> in a one-paragraph article the purpose of which is to show that bilabial apophony is widespread. Monlau 1157 rejects Covarrubias’ *zurra* ‘pelo’ + *burro* and various Basque etyma, and says it is a compound of *churre* ‘pringue gruesa y sucia quc corre de una cosa grasa’ (*DRAE* 416b) and *borra* ‘hez, sedimento, cosa inútil’, but while the consonantal change *z > ch* is widely attested in words of this sort, the opposite change *ch > z* is not, and *zurriburri* is obviously primary. The imitative hypothesis (*DRAE* «voz imitativa» and *DEEH* §7392 *zurr-* ‘onomatopeya’) is, as usual, unjustifiable. Lépelmann also identifies the Basque counterparts of the word as reflexes of a rhyming reduplicalive onomatopoeia, but goes on to suggest (actually he merely says «vergleichen Sie dazu») a relationship with Sp. *zurriar, zurrir*. There is promise in this. *Zurrir*, obviously, is a perfect input candidate for *zurriburri*; semantically, the development ‘make a confused sound’ → ‘the confused sound itself’ → ‘people who carouse, low—class people’ is certainly feasible, and each of the two latter steps is represented in *zurriburri* itself. Given the fact that bilabial apophony is more common in Basque than Spanish, it is probably the case that the actual expansion took place in the former, after which it was reappropriated by bilingual Spanish speakers, especially in Navarre (where, by the way, the greatest range of variability is shown), where the final semantic step to ‘low—class people’ was carried out. *Zurrumburrún* is very closely associated with Basque both formally — since *-u-* is a common final vowel in Basque — and semantically, cf. *surruburru* ‘trabajillos de poca monta’, which suggests, like *zurrumburrún*, a careless, helter-skelter way of doing things.
>
> <sup>9 H. Schuchardt, «Romano-Griechisches», *ZRPh* 30 (1906), 749.</sup>
>
> - [*Structure and Analogy in the Playful Lexicon of Spanish*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GZYDDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201&dq=%22the+consonantal+change+z+%3E+ch%22) (p.199 - 201), David A. Pharies

Comment: Este autor ha desmontado de un plumazo todas las etimologías que recopilo en mi respuesta... :-D

Answer (score 2):

Pues vamos con el Corominas, a ver qué dice:

> *Zurriar, zurriburri, zurrido,* V. *zumbar*.

Bien, pues parece que va a ser un derivado de *zumbar*, a ver qué pone ahí:

> **ZUMBAR**, 1495. Onomatopeya del zumbido. En el sentido de 'burlarse de alguien', 1588, en portugués *zombar*, tendrá el mismo origen, habiendo significado primero 'abuchear, sisear'.
> [...]
> CPT. *Zurriburri*, antes 'zumbido', princ. S. XVII; 'conjunto de gente baja', 'sujeto despreciable', 1611.

Parece que entonces *zurruburri* pudo ser una corrupción de *zumbido*, y entiendo que denotaría el zumbido caótico de la gente hablando por doquier. Dado que Corominas hace referencia a 1611, el año en el que el que se publicó el Covarrubias, vamos a ver si hay suerte... Pues no, según el NTLLE el primer diccionario en el que aparece es en el *Henríquez* de 1679, mas sí que aparece en el *Autoridades*, que dice:

> ZURRIBURRI, s. m. El sugeto vil, despreciable, y de mui baxa esphera. Covarr. dice [¿dónde?] que es voz formada de Zurra, Pelo, y de la voz Burro: como quien dice Pelo de Burro, por ser el pelo de este animal totalmente inutil. Es voz de estilo baxo, y muchas veces se toma por el conjunto de algunos sugetos.

Nótese que por entonces también existía *[churriburri](https://dle.rae.es/?id=96ASkGC)*, que se definía así en el *Autoridades*:

> CHURRIBURRI. s. m. Voz vulgár y baxa con que se dá á entender, y significar que en algun concurso ù otra parte ha havido mucha gente soéz, sucia y común.

Hoy día se usan *churriburri* y *zurriburri* como sinónimos.

En cualquier caso, parece que Covarrubias afirmaba que *zurriburri* no provenía de una corrupción de *zumbido* (que daría origen a la acepción de "barullo, confusión"), sino de "zurra de burro". Pero para rizar más el rizo, cuando en 1899 la Academia se decidió a volver a introducir las etimologías en las palabras de su diccionario, afirmaba:

> **Zurriburri.** (Del vasc. *chori-buru*, cabeza ligera.)

Aunque duró poco porque en 1914 ya había desaparecido esa etimología del diccionario, perdiendo pues fuerza la hipótesis del euskera. En otras ediciones, como las de 1970 y 1984 pone que es "voz imitativa", lo cual tampoco da muchas pistas, aunque puede referirse a lo que afirmaba Corominas de que provendría de una corrupción de "zumbido".

He encontrado una definición de la palabra ya en 1627, por parte de Gonzalo de Correas en su *Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales*:

> Un zurriburri.
>
> Por: onbre leve, baxo i soez, de poka kuenta.
>
> ...
>
> Zurriburri.
>
> Dízese esta palavra para sinifikar kon desprezio persona valadí, baxa i de mui poka kuenta.
>
> > "Es un zurriburri"; "Tanto zurriburri"; "Tantos zurrisburris"; "Todos son unos zurrisburris".

Quien, por cierto, nos aclara que el plural de la palabra sería, nota curiosa, *zurrisburris*.